# Encrypt a meta in HTML

Tags: html, tags, meta-tags

I'mI was wondering if there's a possibility of encrypting a normal code into HTML?

So it doesn't appear like that. Looking for something like "asdasd255asdxzx" is that even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Encrypt the whole page with ssl/https...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypting HTML is possible with Javascript, but this is **NOT useful** in your case because:

- Search engine spiders aren't able to read Javascript (Result: it won't recognize the meta tag).

Meta tags are made for Search engine spiders, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt it … but then no client would understand it because you'd have made the contents a secret.